# React not ordering JSX elements correctly

Tags: html, forms, babeljs, reactjs

I'm new to React.

Here is my code inside a React component:

```
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
  rows.push(
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...></td>
    </tr>
  )
}


return (
  <tr>
    <form className="updateForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <td>
        <table>
          {rows}
        </table>
      </td>

      <td>
        <button id={this.props.id} name="Update" type="button">Update</button>
        <button id={this.props.id} name="Delete" type="button">Delete</button>
        <button id={this.props.id} name="Add" type="button">Add</button>
      </td>
    </form>
  </tr>
```

Here is the output HTML:

```
<tr data-reactid=".au4np63w8w.1.0.1.0.$0">
  <form class="updateForm" data-reactid=".au4np63w8w.1.0.1.0.$0.0"></form>
  <td data-reactid=".au4np63w8w.1.0.1.0.$0.0.0">
    <table data-reactid=".au4np63w8w.1.0.1.0.$0.0.0.0">
      <tbody>
        ...
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td data-reactid=".au4np63w8w.1.0.1.0.$0.0.1">
    <button id="0" name="Update" type="button" data-reactid=".au4np63w8w.1.0.1.0.$0.0.1.0">Update</button>
    <button id="0" name="Delete" type="button" data-reactid=".au4np63w8w.1.0.1.0.$0.0.1.1">Delete</button>
    <button id="0" name="Add" type="button" data-reactid=".au4np63w8w.1.0.1.0.$0.0.1.2">Add</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Notice that the `form` element that is supposed to include the table cells renders so that the table cells are outside of the form. I would expect that it should all be WYSIWYG. Am I doing something wrong or is it an actual bug? BTW, I'm using Babel with Webpack to parse JSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug in React but rather the browser cleaning your erroneous semantics up.

A `form` element is not allowed as a direct child of a `tr` element. That's why your browser/React is outputting the HTML you see.

Paste below HTML in JSBin/Fiddle or the [W3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) and see the results

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <form>
      <td>Hello!</td>
    </form>
  </tr>
</table>
```

A `td` can contain a `form` or a `form` can contain a `table`.